# how to pass font-size in object and how to bind it in html

Tags: angularjs

how can i dynamically change the font-size of div content by passing it in object

```
$scope.Items = [
      { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj:{data:54565463,right:67566,title:'headers',font-size:'20px'}},
      { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:65476756,right:123,title:"Income"}}
      ] 

})
 app.directive('myWidget',function(){

        return{

            restrict:"EA",
            scope:{ 
            title:'@',
            data:'=',
            },
            templateUrl:'spare.html',
            }

        });
```

and how to bind  it in html here is my html

```
<div gridster > 
<ul>
<li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
   <div my-widget data="item.obj" ng-style="myStyle"> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and spare html

```
<span ng-controller="myController" >
<div class="panel-body"  >
<h1  class="title" >{{data.title}}</h1>
<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>{{data.data}}
</h1></div>
 <p id="rightcorner"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i>{{data.right}} 
 </p>
    </span>
```

Comment: actually i m new to angular js can anyone help me out from this

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    var style = JSON.parse(attr['data']) //String parse  to Object
    var or_ele = elem[0] //Here will get orginal dom from angular dom
    if (style['font-size']) {
      var all_style = 'font-size:' + style['font-size'] //Here You Can make all style as string
      or_ele.setAttribute('style', all_style)
    }
  }
})
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Items = [{
      sizeX: 2,
      sizeY: 1,
      row: 0,
      col: 0,
      obj: {
        data: 54565463,
        right: 67566,
        title: 'headers',
        'font-size': '20px'
      }
    },
    {
      sizeX: 2,
      sizeY: 1,
      row: 0,
      col: 0,
      obj: {
        data: 65476756,
        right: 123,
        title: "Income"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
  <div gridster>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in Items track by $index">
        <div data="{{item.obj}}" my-directive>{{item.obj.title}} </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: cool it works fine but u had not included  custom directives how can we do that by adding custom directives

Comment: Can u try with my Example?If u tryied Share that code?

Comment: app.directive('myWidget',function(){
     
  return{
   app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    var style = JSON.parse(attr['data']) //String parse  to Object
    var or_ele = elem[0] //Here will get orginal dom from amgular dom
    if (style['font-size']) {
      var all_style = 'font-size:' + style['font-size'] //Here You Can make all style as string
      or_ele.setAttribute('style', all_style)
    }
  }
   
   restrict:"EA",
   scope:{ 
   title:'@',
   data:'=',
   },
   templateUrl:'spare.html',
   }
  
  })

Comment: for my controllervar app=angular.module('myApp',['gridster'])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
 
 $scope.Items = [
  { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj:{data:54565463,right:67566,title:'Headers',} },
  { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:65476756,right:12344,title:"Income"}}]})

Comment: In html  u have set attribute --------><div data="{{item.obj}}" my-directive></div>

Not like this: <div data="tem.obj" my-directive>

Comment: i want to share my code with u can u provide me any source

Comment: thank you so much@sudhakar ayyar  can  i different styles for multiple div

Comment: you had not given permission to access that folder @sudhakar ayyar

Comment: I will send the files today

Comment: child div is not resizing its size along with change of parent div height and width . Child div should automatically change its size along with parent div dynamically  and i m using angular gridster.js for it    when i drag a gridster  the  child div inside is not changing its size it stays  in same position

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I were you would be the following:

1. Create a class in a .css file:

   .font-size-20 {
       font-size: 20px;
   }
   .red {
       font-color: red
   }
2. Save the class name in your Json:

   $scope.Items = [
     { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj:{data:54565463,right:67566,title:'headers', styles: 'font-size-20 red'}},
     { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:65476756,right:123,title:"Income"}}
     ]
3. In your html, you can bind the class:

   `class="{{item.obj.styles}}"`

Comment: can u please provide me  fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use,  `ng-style="{ 'font-size': item.obj.font-size} "`

**Html:**

```
<div gridster >
    <ul>
    <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <div my-widget data="item.obj" ng-style="{ 'font-size': item.obj.font-size ? item.obj.font-size : '14px'} "> </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```